# Using .NET 4.x in Unity on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine

Can you use .NET4x in Unity on Ubuntu?
I have install the .NET6 on my system but there is no option in the unity settings. ¿Do I have to install an older version of the .net or is this even possible?
Thank you in advance
[I only have this two versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDffI.png)

Comment: .Net 4x is .Net Framework, but .Net 6 is based on the cross platform .Net Core

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that it is not possible to use .NET Framework on linux OS properly due to it not being cross-platform like .NET core and .NET 5+. You can use a windows virtual machine and use it. Also, you can try to install mono IDE and WINE to install .exe applications or software

Answer (score 0):

From [.NET Profile Support](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/dotnetProfileSupport.html)

> Unity aims to support the vast majority of the APIs in the .NET Standard 2.0 profile on all platforms. While not all platforms fully support the .NET Standard, libraries which aim for cross-platform compatibility should target the .NET Standard 2.0 profile. **The .NET 4.x profile includes a much larger API surface, including parts which may work on few or no platforms.**

=> Most probably not no